# How call the multiple class in PHP using json_encode?

Tags: php, mysql, json

Can anyone help me fix this problem? 
I'm trying to call my class in this file (all-function.php)

```
class rating_star{
        function loop_star($rating){
            ......
        }
}
```

i'm calling this class in searching-data.php

```
 $que1_search = mysql_query("SELECT p.id AS id,pd.name AS nama,pd.price AS
 harga,pd.stock as stok,pd.rating AS rating, pd.rater AS rater,pdisc.discount 
AS disc, pi.image AS imgnya,t.tags AS tagnya FROM product p,product_detail 
pd,product_discount pdisc,product_image PI,tags t WHERE p.id=pd.id_product AND 
p.id=pdisc.id_product AND p.id=pi.id_product AND p.id=t.id_product AND pd.name 
LIKE'%$_COOKIE[cari_data]%' GROUP BY p.tanggal DESC");


    while ($data_que1_search = mysql_fetch_array($que1_search)) {
        include "../../_plugin/_config/all-function.php";
        echo "
        <li style='margin-top:10px;'>
        <div id='img-search' style='border-bottom:2px solid #3b3b3b;height:270px'>
            <img src='../../_img/_barang/$data_que1_search[imgnya]' height='250px' style='margin:10px 0px'>
        </div>
        <div id='ket-search' class='c-back-grey'>
            <p class='c-f-left c-text-a-left c-bold'>$data_que1_search[nama]</p>
            <p class='c-f-left c-text-a-left c-color-pink c-bold' style='width:280px;margin-bottom:10px;'>Rp. $data_que1_search[harga],00</p>
            <div id='for-star-1' style='margin:5px 0px 10px -65px;'>";
            $rate = $data_que1_search['rating']/$data_que1_search['rater'];
```

> ```
>           $call_f_star = new rating_star;
>
>           $call_f_star->loop_star($rate);
> ```

```
            echo "
                <p class='c-font-12 c-color-dark' style='margin-top:-3px'> Rating : ".$rate."</p>
            </div>
            <p class='c-f-left c-text-a-left c-color-dark-blue c-bold' style='margin-top:10px;width:280px'>$data_que1_search[stok]</p>
             <div class='c-clean'></div>
            </div>
            <div class='c-clean'></div>
       </li>
        ";
    }
```

the error said that

> Fatal error: Cannot redeclare class rating_star in
>   C:\wamp\www\POKOKO_plugin_config\all-function.php on line 5

i heard that i can using json_encode for this case, but until now i still can't understand about json_encode. Can somebody help me to fix my project?

Thank You.

Comment: What is your case? What do you want to do? `json_encode` encodes something to JSON. I don't think that's what you want to do. http://php.net/json_encode

Answer (score 0):

Including a file in PHP runs the script.  Since your script defines a class, if you include it more than once you're attempting to re-define the class. To make sure you're script is only executed once:

```
include_once "../../_plugin/_config/all-function.php";
```

But even better, don't include a file in a loop.  It's best practice to include once at the top of your script.